# Removing Unused parameters warning in QtCreator

Tags: c, gcc, qt-creator, unused-variables

I added this to my `.pro` file  but I stil get warnings :

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_OFF = -Wunused-parameter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
... = -Wno-unused-parameter
```

Please [see here for details](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

Or try

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_OFF -= -Wunused-parameter
```

Note the `-` in front of the `=`.

Comment: I still get the warning when I rebuild

Comment: It worked with `QMAKE_CFLAGS = -Wno-unused-parameter`.

Comment: @YoussefBouhjira `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS = -Wno-unused-parameter` in this case

Answer (score 15):

Use `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON += -Wno-unused-parameter`,
because the flags in QMAKE_CXX_FLAGS will always before QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON, and QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON contains the flag -Wall. This means your flag will be overwrite by flag -Wall.